# primefaces - edit row without one cell

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have dataTable with row editing, but i dont need to edit one of my cells **(user.username)**. How can i do this in primefaces? Is this possible? I try remove **p:cellEditor** for one cell but it does not work on my tablet because when I use this in a DataTable, this column is empty.

Thanks!

my code:

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
        <p:contextMenu for="dataTable">
            <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="dataTable" icon="ui-icon-close"
                actionListener="#{userMB.deleteUser}" />
        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="user" styleClass="DataTableUsers"
            value="#{userMB.userList}" paginator="true" rows="5"
            rowKey="#{user.user_id}" selection="#{userMB.selectedUser}"
            selectionMode="single" filteredValue="#{userMB.filteredUsers}"
            editable="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" immediate="true" listener="#{userMB.onEdit}"
                update=":form:messages, :form:dataTable" process="@this" />
            <p:column sortBy="name" filterBy="name" id="name" headerText="Name">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{user.name}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Please Enter Name"
                            validatorMessage="Name is too short!">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="2"></f:validateLength>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="surname" filterBy="surname" headerText="Surname">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.surname}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{user.surname}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Please Enter Surname!"
                            validatorMessage="Surname is too short!">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="2"></f:validateLength>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="username" filterBy="username"
                headerText="Index number">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:inputText value="#{user.username}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="userDescription" filterBy="userDescription"
                headerText="descript">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.userDescription}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{user.userDescription}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Please Enter User Description" />
                    </f:facet>

                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:6%" headerText="Edit">
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="New User" oncomplete="newUserDialog.show()"
                    icon="ui-icon-star" title="Creates new user" />

            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the component that holds the `user.username` value to `<h:outputText>`

```
<h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
```

and you will have the value read-only.